# Show dimensions in product page for opencart

Tags: php, css, opencart, dimensions, opencart-module

I need to display the product dimensions in the product page.
Here is my code but this is not executed.
i added in catalog/controller/product/product.php

```
<?php
$this->data['length'] = number_format($product_info['length'],2) .  ' cm';
    $this->data['width'] = number_format($product_info['width'],2) .  ' cm';
    $this->data['height'] = number_format($product_info['height'],2) .  ' cm';
```

and in the same file

```
$this->data['text_dimensions'] = $this->language->get('text_dimensions');
        $this->data['text_by'] = $this->language->get('text_by');
```

and in catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

```
<?php echo $length; ?><?php echo $text_by; ?><?php echo width; ?><?php echo $text_by; ?><?php echo $height; ?><?php echo $text_by; ?>
```

and in my catalog/language/english/product/product.php

```
$_['text_dimensions'] = 'Dimensions:';
        $_['text_by'] = 'x';
```

After try this code dimension are not showing in opencart.

Comment: What opencart version are you working on?

Comment: Have you passed the language variables via the controller?
If so, do they appear on the page in the place?

Comment: opencart 2.1.0.2 version

Comment: for opencart 2.1.0.2 you should store your variables in $data array instead of $this->data , which will be passed to the view. It is specific for OC 2.x

Comment: i tried in catalog/controller/product/product.php file $data['length'] = number_format($product_info['length'],2) .  ' cm';
     $data['width'] = number_format($product_info['width'],2) .  ' cm';
     $data['height'] = number_format($product_info['height'],2) .  ' cm';

Comment: but it is also not working. in view i write <?php echo $length; ?> it shows undefined variable length.

Comment: can you specify approx line where you inserted your code here https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/2.1.0.2/upload/catalog/controller/product/product.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [controller file](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/2.1.0.2/upload/catalog/controller/product/product.php) for the version you are working on (OC 2.1.0.2)

$this->data is no more used for passing variables to a view in Opencart 2.x . Instead the rendering method accepts the second parameter, which is an array of variables to pass into the view

```
$this->load->view('default/template/error/not_found.tpl', $data)
```

Usually `$data` variable is used.

You need to insert your variables into the array before it will be passed to the rendering method.

Another issue I spot that you are hardcoding dimensions (cm), which probably can be retrieved from the system as well.

One more thing: do not forget to pass the language variables you created as well as other variables via controller.

Comment: i tried in catalog/controller/product/product.php file $data['length'] = $product_info['length']; $data['width'] = $product_info['width']; $data['height'] = $product_info['height']; in view page i write <?php echo $length; ?> it shows undefined variable length

Comment: can you specify approx line where you inserted your code here https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/2.1.0.2/upload/catalog/controller/product/product.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Controller code :

```
$data['weight']  = $this->weight->format($product_info['weight'], $product_info['weight_class_id']);
$data['length']  = $this->length->format($product_info['length'], $product_info['length_class_id']);
$data['width']   = $this->length->format($product_info['width'], $product_info['length_class_id']);
$data['height']  = $this->length->format($product_info['height'], $product_info['length_class_id']);
```

View file (product.tpl) code :

```
<li><?php echo $weight; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $length; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $width; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $height; ?></li>
```

It worked for me in OpenCart version 2.1.x